# Disable automatic email log

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am using PHP `mail()` function to send a mail based on my MySQL query result from a cron job at every minute interval.

All is ok, but it creates a log file for each `mail` automatically. Which exceeds disk space after each 2-3 days.

I haven't configured any setting for sending mails.

How can I can disable this automatic logging?

Comment: What is the log file? ``/var/log/maillog``?

Comment: disabling logging altogether is usually a bad idea since it takes away important information to debug problems, analyze intrusions, spam incidents etc. consider using a log management tool that compresses/removes older logs instead. Example: logrotate (http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to call PHP's mail() function yourself since there are so many things you can do wrong leading up to that - use a wrapper like [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead.

With that in place, it's possible to use their SMTP classes directly meaning emails will not go through the local mail server and thus not get logged.

As Gryphius said, you should be rotating/compressing logs anyway - though I'm surprised if you're not since most OS packages for postfix/exim/sendmail have that already set up. Also you must have very little disk space if you're running out so quickly!